# Why don't we use $ as end marker for input in PDA?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I am reading Theory of Computation by Peter Linz. The transitions for PDA uses $\epsilon$ as end marker for input string. For example if the final state is
 $q_1$ then the transition is written like $\delta(q_0,\epsilon,z)=(q_1,z)$.

Why don't they write the transition as $\delta(q_0,\$,z)=(q_1,z)$.

Comment: We want to have possibility to allow stack to become empty without going to final state.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is not a "marker".

Comment: @rici I know it's not a marker. But they are treating it like a marker.

Comment: @KishanKumar If they did that, it would be wrong. An $\varepsilon$-transition can trigger at any point in time, not only at the end of the input.

Comment: $\$$ is the "bottom of stack" marker. You can't introduce "end of input" markers without changing the input language (making it prefix-free).